# Node.js Object function Number() { [native code] } has no method 'isInteger'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Some methods and fields are missing from Node.js 'Number' class. For instance,

```
console.log(Number.isInteger(5));
```

Gives, "TypeError: Object function Number() { [native code] } has no method 'isInteger'", while

```
console.log(Number.isFinite(5));
```

runs fine.

Similarly,

```
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

returns 'undefined', while

```
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE);
```

> returns '1.7976931348623157e+308' as expected.

What is the issue? [Mozilla Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) network says all above methods should work fine.

Comment: What version of node.js are you using?

Comment: Node.js --version returned "v0.10.25". This is embarrassing, how can I be using a version so old. But running the same commands on Node console (node-console.com/script/code) returned the same results as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the latest version of Node.js resolved the issue.